# Form validation not working, using validate.js

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to use the validate.js file for form validation.

I followed everything that is said here: http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/

But it doesn't give me any messages.

The code works, it doesn't submit if one of those items is wrong, but it's not showing the messages.

Any idea what I missed?

My index:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validate.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<td>
<form name="form">
<tr>
Voornaam: <p><input type="text" name="voornaam"></p>
</tr>
<tr>
Achternaam: <p><input type="text" name="achternaam"></p>
</tr>
<tr>
Telefoonnummer: <p><input type="text" name="telefoon"></p>
</tr>
<tr>
Emailadres: <p><input type="text" name="email"></p>
</tr>
<tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Stuur op">
</tr>
</form>
</td>
</table>

<script>
var validator = new FormValidator('form', [{
    name: 'voornaam',
    display: 'required',    
    rules: 'required'
}, {
    name: 'achternaam',
    display: 'required', 
    rules: 'required'
},{
    name: 'telefoon',
    display: 'required', 
    rules: 'numeric'
},{
    name: 'email',
    display: 'required', 
    rules: 'valid_email'
}], function(errors, event) {
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        // Show the errors
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the validate.js file I'm using:

[validate.min.js](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/validate.min.js)

Comment: Where the // Show the errors comment appears you need to have your error message display script. Have a look at the authors page and just  before the Custom Validation Rules the author gives an example of how to display the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs properly. Error handling has to be visualized by yourself. You have a callback that accepts error information parameters, but displaying the errors has to be done by you.

For example:

```
var validator = new FormValidator('form', [{...}], function(errors, event) {
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            alert(errors[i].message);
        }
    }
});
```

The docs provides another example. Just give it an intensive read.

Comment: Thanks I am new to javascript. I want to display all the messages, I used this code, but now it only displays the last name message? function(errors, event) {
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById('berichten').innerHTML = (errors[i].message);
   
        }
    }

Comment: As I said. Take a look on the docs, there is a perfect example of that. In your case you're replacing the inner html on each iteration. Instead concatenate all error messages in one string, and put it in your inner html. Check it out - http://pastie.org/8620361